# Prove that the funtion is differentiable

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Help me with this exercise :)

$$ \text{Let }\space f(x, y) =
\begin{cases}
(x^2+y^2)\sin\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}},  & \text{if $(x, y) \ne (0,0)$} \\
0 & \text{if $(x, y) = (0, 0)$}  \\
\end{cases}$$

Prove $f$ is 
differentiable at $(0,0)$, but that $F_x(x,y) $ and $F_y(x,y)$ are not continuous at $(0,0).$

Comment: What does it mean for a function to be differentiable at a point?

Answer (score 1):

Putting $\textbf{x}=(x,y)$, we have that:

$$f(\textbf{0}+\textbf{h})=||\textbf{h}||^2\sin\left(\frac{1}{||\textbf{h}||}\right)=f(\textbf{0})+ ||\textbf{h}||^2\sin\left(\frac{1}{||\textbf{h}||}\right).$$

Since $||\textbf{h}||\sin\left(\frac{1}{||\textbf{h}||}\right) \rightarrow 0$ as $\textbf{h} \rightarrow 0$, it is clear that $f$ is differentiable at $0$ with derivative being the zero-map.

A straightforward computation should show non-continuity of the partial derivatives.